# Does a Corsair CMSO8GX3M1C1600C11 RAM works on a MBP mid 2012?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory, compatibility

Does a Corsair CMSO8GX3M1C1600C11 RAM works on a MBP mid 2012?

I know Corsair has mac compatible memory sticks **but** this one I mention is the only one I can get at my location.

From what I see the latency is a bit different: 11-11-11-28 instead of 11-11-11-30.

I really need to upgrade my RAM but can't get any of the "mac compatible" kits. :-/

Comment: Actually the lover the number the better :)

Comment: Ohh, that I "know" but my worry is that the mac will be "picky" and it will randomly fail etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will work fine with Mac.

I have personal experience. I've tested out that configuration.

Comment: How do you know? any references ? personal experience ?

Comment: Personal experience. I've tested out that configuration.